# jQuery Ajax spinner not displaying in IE7

Tags: ajax, jquery, spinner

I am trying to display an ajax spinner when loading AJAX content.

The following code appears to work fine in Firefox but not in IE7.  The functions to show and hide the spinner are being called but the browser just does not display it.

Here is the jQuery:

```
        $.ajax({ 
            url: filterorSearch,
            data: {filterParams: JSON.stringify(filters), requestTime: new Date().getTime()},
            beforeSend: function(){
                showLoadingGraphic();
            },
            complete: function(){
                hideLoadingGraphic();
            },
            success: function(data){
                $("#BreakingNews").html(data);
                GetRelatedarticles();                
            }
        });

    function showLoadingGraphic() {
        alert("show");
        var showSpinner = $('#page-placeholder-wrapper #main-left').prepend('<div id="ajaxLoader"></div>');
        return showSpinner;
    }

    function hideLoadingGraphic() {
        alert("hide");
        var hideSpinner = $('#ajaxLoader').remove();
        return hideSpinner;
    }
```

And the associated CSS for the spinner:

```
#page-placeholder-wrapper #main-left 
{
    position:relative;
    }

#ajaxLoader 
{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.7) url("../images/icon-ajax-loading.gif") no-repeat center center;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:9999;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you working try this:

```
    background: url("../images/icon-ajax-loading.gif") no-repeat center center rgba(255,255,255,.7);
```

I don't know why the rgba has to be last!

**[EDIT]**

IE does not support rgba, therefore with it starting on `background:` it errors and the rest of the line isn't executed for the css

See: [Browser Support for RGBa](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/)

Answer (score 1):

Might be problems with Z sorting of your DOM elements;

IE handles Z sorting of objects in a bit different way then other browsers. Try setting z-index on your wrapper element and it should help. Generally it's a best practice if you want to save you troubles with elements positioned with relatie or absolute positioning to always give their parent proper z-index;

Having the actual page to debug would make it easier.

Comment: That's not it i'm afraid.  Am working localy for a client so publishing the page is not an option.  It would be nice and appreciate the input :)

Comment: It looks as thoug IE is not performing the prepend when i check for the length of it in the show function it comes back as 0.

Comment: hmm, wild guess - try adding zoom:1 to the wrapper element to trigger the hasLayout on it - might be this - or missing hasLayout somewhere higher in the DOM tree

Comment: are you 100% that beforeSend is being triggered in ie? does it trigger the alert? thought it was rendering issue but if you say it's not adding the element at all must be something else

Comment: hasLayout did not fix it.  beforeSend is being triggered, have tested with alerts etc.

Comment: just to confirm - latest version of jQuery? not a single error in IE7?

Answer (score 1):

JQuery actually fires events when it's doing ajax.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#ajaxIndicator').show();
 }).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('#ajaxIndicator').hide();
 });
```

This will save you a lot of time over manually doing it for each individual call.

You could have a DIV relative to the top of the document which you can show/hide which overlays everything else on the page.  (I forget the exact CSS which makes it always be 200px from the top of the screen, etc) update: I think it's position:fixed, although I'm not sure how well this will work in IE.

```
  <body>
    <div id="ajaxIndicator" style="position:fixed; top:200px; text-align:center">
        <img src="../indicator.gif" /> Loading ...
    </div>

    ...
```

Comment: That does not work either.  I appreciate the input but i think there must be somethign amiss elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of my sanity and getting this done today.

I have added the "ajaxLoader" element to the markup, hidden initially with CSS and then show/hide when AJAX starts/stops.

This works fine for all browsers.

Thanks to all for their input.