# Use Spin.js In Grails GSP

Tags: grails, spinner, gsp

I am trying to use spin.js in my grails GSP. I am not sure if spin.js will work for `input type= submit` or not. Below is my code. I tried too many things but am not getting the spinner to work. I have to put it in the location on the page specified in the code below. I have put spin.js as shown: `webapp/js/spin.js`
Please suggest me how can I use spin.js in my following code. Thanks.

```
        <g:javascript src="spin.js" />
        <g:form name="selectionForm" url="[controller:'Resource',action:'crawl']">
                    ***put spinner here on submit***
                <g:select name="websiteSelection"
                            from="${websitesList.website}" id="mySelect"
                            class="styled-select" value="select" /><
                <input type = "submit" name="selection" value="CRAWL" >                                  </table>
        </g:form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#selectionForm').submit(
                    function() {
                        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr(
                                'disabled', 'disabled');
                    });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow, after debugging through chrome, I found that the js file wasn't being loaded. After rearranging my code, it worked. I had to place the linking statement for javascript file right above my script tag.

```
<g:javascript src="generateSpinner.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#selectionForm').submit(function() {
        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

    $('#btnPerformSave').click(function() {
        spinnerInit();
    });
</script>
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

spinner.js ?

Just wondering if you are over thinking this a little ..

I have plenty of spinners working - generally when the site is busy doing something the spinner comes on.. to get default jquery spinner working try this.

under your BuildConfig.groovy ensure you have plugin dependency:

```
runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
```

in your layouts/main.gsp

```
<g:javascript library="jquery"/>
```

then where ever you wish for the spinner to appear (as in i.e. your menu bar at the top or something) add the following:

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
<img src="${createLinkTo(dir:'images',file:'spinner.gif')}" alt="Spinner" />
</div>
```

That by default will load up the spinner class from your default css provided by grails and kick in when your site is busy...

Hope it answers your question, also found this guide which might be of use: http://blog.oio.de/2010/11/08/how-to-create-a-loading-animation-spinner-using-jquery/

I should point out actually my sites do a ajax a lot so the spinner is kicked in from the default application.js (either in web-app/js or grails-app/assets/javascripts [2.4+])

So to get your button working  as per guide above you could try this on your form page:

```
...
  <input type = "submit" id="submitButton" name="selection" value="CRAWL" >      
...
</form>
<g:javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitButton').click(function() {
        $('#spinner').show();
    });
});
</g:javascript>
```

notice id added to the suubmitbutton and then a further java script added under the form end tag...

Also http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitButton.html

```
<g:submitButton name="update" value="Update" />
```

If you wanted you could use  grails form tags all the way...

Comment: Yes. this approach also I tried but it doesnt work for browsers like Safari and IE 7, 8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758871/jquery-ajax-spinner-not-displaying-in-ie7

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I got it working. The js file wasn't getting linked. I didnt know that the linking tag had to be right above the script tag :)

Comment: cool :) just saw you had a new question of it not working on lots of browsers :) maybe you wanna close it down if it works on all now :)

Comment: Was going to also mention that if you define/call jquery in your layouts/main.gsp.. this would then mean all your oages wirhin your site have access to jquery.